# iOS CoreBluetooth:Sending data from central and getting response from peripheral

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I am developing a Bluetooth app. I have connected to the bluetooth device and found the services and characteristics in it. I am facing problem in sending write request from central and receiving response from peripheral. I have written code as below to write data. How will I know that peripheral received that data? Can I show any alert in peripheral. And, in the same way, I want to receive the data from the peripheral so that the central should show an alert that it has got response from peripheral.

Here is the below code I have written

```
  - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:  
  (CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
   if (!error) {
    printf("Characteristics of service with UUID : %s found\r\n",[self   
   CBUUIDToString:service.UUID]);
    for(int i=0; i < service.characteristics.count; i++) {
        CBCharacteristic *c = [service.characteristics objectAtIndex:i];
        printf("Found characteristic %s\r\n",[ self CBUUIDToString:c.UUID]);
        CBService *s = [peripheral.services objectAtIndex:(peripheral.services.count - 1)];
        if([self compareCBUUID:service.UUID UUID2:s.UUID])
        {
            printf("Finished discovering characteristics");

            break;
        }
     }

  }
   else {
    printf("Characteristic discorvery unsuccessfull !\r\n");
  }

  }
```

for writing the value

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:  
   (CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
  {
    NSString *payloadMessage = @"Hello";
    NSData *payload = [payloadMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [peripheral writeValue:payload forCharacteristic:characteristic    
   type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];

 }
```

and i need to get the version of the ble device i.e GET_VERSION = 0x4a;
please help me regarding this or else provide any examples for writing and reading data from the both devices.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that a Bluetooth central can receive data from a peripheral -

1. It can issue an explicit read request for a characteristic
2. It can subscribe for notifications on a characteristic - in this case the peripheral will notify the central when the value changes or these is new data.  This is more efficient as it avoids the central having to constantly poll the peripheral for data that may not have changed.

Regards of which method you use, the data will be delivered via a call to your `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:` delegate method.

It seems you are a bit confused as to the purpose of this method as your code issues a write request there, which probably isn't what you want.

When it comes to writing data, you can write the data with or without a response.  Your code specifies with response.  In this case, when the peripheral acknowledges the write, your `didWriteValueForCharacteristic` delegate method is called - this is how you know that the data was received.

Some simple code to implement the behaviour you described in your question is:

```
 -(void)sendData:(NSData *)data {

      [self.connectedPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:self.someCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];

 }


- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
             error:(NSError *)error {
         if (error == nil) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wrote characteristic" message:@"Successfully wrote characteristic" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"ok"];
            [alert show];
         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"Error writing characteristic %@",error);
         }
     }

  -(void)readCharacteristic {
    [self.connectedPeripheral readCharacteristic:self.someOtherCharacteristic];
}




- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
    {
     if (error == nil) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Read characteristic" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Successfully read characteristic %@",characteristic.value] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"ok"];
            [alert show];
         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"Error reading characteristic %@",error);
         }

     }
```

Comment: i need to read a value from the peripheral device that it has version GET_VERSION = 0x4a;like this so what should i need to do  in didUpdateValueForCharacteristic delegate method .

Comment: I don't know what that means.  You read and write characteristics.  You need to refer to your device's documentation to determine which characteristics you need to write to or read from

Comment: Thanks paulw.for example if i want to get the version details of the peripheral device .i had only details like above "0x4a" i think this info i need to fill in the buffer to receive response from device . what should i do in the didUpdateValueForCharacteristic delegate method to retrieve version details ...iam new to iOS please help